# PyCharm case sensitive auto-complete

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

I can't find a way in PyCharm to disable case sensitive on auto complete.
When I type the first letter lowercase, it won't suggest me methods which has first letter uppercase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just uncheck `Match case` in this setting: `Editor -> General -> Code Completion`

[image: Just uncheck Match case in this setting]